# UPDATE TABLE split() in mysql

Tags: mysql

How would I do the following:

```
code    code_base
en-DE   en
yue-mn  yue
en      en
```

In python, I would do:

```
code_base = code.split('-')[0]
```

How would I do the equivalent in mysql, in pseudocode:

```
UPDATE table SET code_base=code.split('-')[0]
```

Comment: What's with your title?  Why does it say `ALTER TABLE`?

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to "split" a string in MySQL.  Splitting usually returns an array, which MySQL doesn't have.

What you can do is, get the substring from `0` up until the first `-`.  Check out [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
UPDATE table SET code_base=SUBSTRING_INDEX(code, '-', 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to perform a split:

```
UPDATE table 
    SET code_base= SUBSTRING_INDEX(code, '-', 1)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table SET code_base= LEFT(code, LOCATE('-', code)-1)
```